# iOS - Disable UITabbarItem from AppDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbaritem

I want to disable and enable later an UITabbarItem from the AppDelegate.m. (To be specific, on didFinishLaunchingWithOptions should it be disabled and after a NSURLConnection it should be enabled. I already tried creating a external method in the First View Controller and calling it from the Delegate, but it do not work. Here is my attempt:

**FirstViewController.m:**

```
-(void)enableDataTab {

[[[[self.tabBarController tabBar] items] objectAtIndex:1] setEnabled:YES];

}
```

**AppDelegate.m:**

```
    homeVC = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];
    [homeVC disableDataTab];
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this (in the view controller):

```
self.tabBarItem.enabled = NO;
```

Or like this (in the app delegate):

```
myFirstViewController.tabBarItem.enabled = NO;
```

The tab bar item representing a view controller is a property of that view controller.

Also, don't say

```
homeVC = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];
```

That makes a whole new FirstViewController. You don't want a new FirstViewController; you want the one that's already there as a child of the tab bar controller.

Comment: You will need to obtain a reference to the actual view controller. I could give a better answer if you showed more of what you're doing in the app delegate and more about how the app itself is laid out. Is the root view controller a tab bar controller, and if so, are you creating it in code or in a storyboard? You need to reveal that kind of thing if you want more specific instructions.

Comment: Okay, as I sad the AppDelegate starts a NSURlConnection and downloads some data at the application launch point. The UIViewControllers are set up in a storyboard. Maybe this is important: the rootViewVC is a TabBarController and the item I want to trigger belongs to a UITableViewController, which is embedded in a NavigationController. I'm sorry for making this so complicated. For now I have found a workaround: external BOOL and a NSTimer in the FirstViewController.